# Spring 4 - addResourceHandlers не подключает статические ресурсы

Tags: spring, spring-security

Я использую  Spring 4, конфигурацию на аннотациях. Пробовал разные комбинации добавления css и js  на jsp страницу, но ни  одна не работала. 
Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфигурация:

1

```
 @Configuration
    public class NewConfigure extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }
    }
```

2

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{NewConfigure.class};
    }


    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

3

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("**/style/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                     .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                     .antMatchers("/basket/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                      .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**").permitAll()
                     .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index").failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

                     http.csrf().disable();
        }
```

AppConfig // бины для работы:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.vdp.*"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })

public class AppConfig {
```

Последний способ подключения:

```
<link href="/resources/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/ >
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Когда вы пишете такую штуку:

```
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Это подразумевает, что каталог `/resources` у вас находится в каталоге `/webapp`, поскольку для того чтобы получить путь к данному ресурсу Spring использует метод `ServletContext.getResource()`

> When you call getResource() on a specific application context, and the
>   location path specified doesn't have a specific prefix, you will get
>   back a Resource type that is appropriate to that particular
>   application context. For example, assume the following snippet of code
>   was executed against a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext instance:
>
> Resource template =
>   ctx.getResource("some/resource/path/myTemplate.txt");
>
> What would be returned would be a ClassPathResource; if the same
>   method was executed against a FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
>   instance, you'd get back a FileSystemResource. **For a**
>   **WebApplicationContext, you'd get back a ServletContextResource, and so**
>   **on.**

[Документация](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)

Вы, перепутав, все положили в стандартный Maven каталог `/resources`, и таким образом отправили статику в classpath приложения. Откройте сформированный WAR файл и посмотрите где эти файлы оказались - `/WEB-INF/classes`.

Вот пример того как может быть сконфигурирован доступ к статическим ресурсам:

```
spring-mvc-java-config » tree
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       └── webapp
│           └── WEB-INF
│               ├── fonts
│               ├── html
│               ├── i18n
│               └── images
│               └── scripts
│               └── styles
│               └── images
```

**WebMvcConfigurerAdapter**

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/styles/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/fonts/");
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**")
            .antMatchers("/styles/**")
            .antMatchers("/images/**")
            .antMatchers("/fonts/**");
    }
}
```

И не забывайте добавлять [context path](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) приложения, когда прописываете URL статического ресурса в JSP, Thymeleaf и прочем.

Comment: Я не перепутал, просто пробовал разные варианты. Спасибо большое за помошь, все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно удалять папку resources и перемещать все ваши статические ресурсы под WEB-INF (как это указано в ответе выше). Просто должны соблюдаться следующие шаги:

1) Папка resources должна быть под webapp.

2) В вашей конфигурации должен быть прописан этот метод:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

3) Лично я прописываю путь в моих JSP страницах с помощью JSTL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/test.css" />" />
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/test.js" />"></script>
```

Для этого импортируем JSTL Core библиотеку. Добавляем в JSP следующее:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Также вместо JSTL Core можно использовать ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

В итоге, у меня подхватываются CSS и JS ресурсы на ура :)